# IOS 10 Interractive transition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewanimationtransition

Swift 3 - IOS 10 - Xcode 8

I want create an interactive transition. I have two view controller :

- RootViewController (Source - SVC)
- PlayerViewController (Destination - DVC)

But, when my DVC is presented, it never execute my animation and related methods. It execute the system animation.

My RootViewController :

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    var transitionManager = PlayerTransitionManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.transitionManager.sourceViewController = self

        // ...
    }

}
```

My TransitionManager :

```
class PlayerTransitionManager: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    private var presenting = false
    private var interactive = false

    private var enterPanGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    private var exitPanGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    var sourceViewController: RootViewController! {
        didSet {
            self.enterPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
            self.enterPanGesture.addTarget(self, action:#selector(PlayerTransitionManager.handleOnstagePan(_:)))
            self.sourceViewController.playerV.addGestureRecognizer(self.enterPanGesture)
        }
    }
    var destinationViewController: UIViewController! {
        didSet {
            self.exitPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
            self.exitPanGesture.addTarget(self, action:#selector(PlayerTransitionManager.handleOffstagePan(_:)))
            self.destinationViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.exitPanGesture)
        }
    }

    func handleOnstagePan(_ pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        let translation = pan.translation(in: pan.view!)
        let d =  translation.y / pan.view!.bounds.height * -0.5

        switch (pan.state) {

        case .began:
            self.interactive = true
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // OK
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerVC") // OK
            controller.transitioningDelegate = self
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            self.destinationViewController = controller
            self.sourceViewController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil) // present with system annimation
            break

        case .changed:
            // Never Executed
            self.update(d)
            break

        default: // .Ended, .Cancelled, .Failed ...
            // Finish or cancel.
            // No impact because annimation never started
            break
        }
    }

    func handleOffstagePan(_ pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        // For dismiss
        // Same problem
    }

    // MARK: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol methods

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // Nerver Executed
        // ...
    }

    func offStage(amount: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform {
        // Nerver Executed
        // ...
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        // Nerver Executed
        // ...
    }

    // MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods
    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        // Nerver Executed
        // ...
    }
    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        // Nerver Executed
        // ...
    }

    func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        // Nerver Executed
        // ...
    }
    func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        // Nerver Executed
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And how did you set `PlayerViewController` as destinationViewController ?

Comment: Try to set `PlayerViewController`'s delegate before instead of in .began case...

Comment: I had the same issue, and after many attempts the problem "went away". So maybe a "Product > Clean" was needed.